# How can I stop filling an object with fluid when it is full?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I want to simulate some oil going from one tank 1 M^3 then down in a pipe and filling up a std 55 Gal barrel.

See image:

[image]

I've got several problems with this such as how to stop filling the barrel when it is full so it doesn't spill?

Also, if I use inflow it will overspill a lot! I could not get to do it with a very small pipe so is there a way to do it with a small pipe? Right now the pipe has a 1 foot diameter which is not realistic!

I can provide the file if needed.

Comment: So the problem is over-spill? You can turn off the *inflow object* by key framing the *enable* property. And you can use a smaller pipe by using higher resolution. Please be more specific about your problem.